# Build, Modify, Output Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to accomplish the following...if it's asking too much in a single question then some simple steps on what events to use will still help.

There are 2 blank textareas sitting next to eachother - Input and Output.  Between them are two inputs Before and After.  I want to type or paste a list of words into Input separated by line break, for example:

```
melons
peaches
apples
```

And then use the Before and After inputs to add in a word/phrase/symbol before and after each keyword.  So if I type 'buy' in before and 'today' in after, the Output text area will display:

```
buy melons today
buy peaches today
buy apples today
```

I'd like to accomplish this without having any page refreshing.  We can assume the form elements are named as follows:

```
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="before" />
<input type="text" id="after" />
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

I've been try to at least get the Input text to display in Output using this code, but that's not even working:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#input').keyup(function(e){
            $('#output').html($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Any guidance would be awesome!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Normally, on Stack Overflow, you're expected to try and accomplish your task before asking the question, posting the relevant code when you get stuck.  I would start by looking at the String and Array methods [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Comment: Yeah, I had started to just try to get the text from Input to display in Output but couldn't even get that to work.  I just updated my original post with that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a compact one:

```
$("#input,#before,#after").on("keyup", function () {
    $("#output").val(
    $.map($("#input").val().split("\n"), function (n, i) {
        return $("#before").val() + " "+ n + " " + $("#after").val();
    }).join("\n"));
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/terryleonhart/WsM9J/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
function update_output(){
    //Split input by newline
    var input_words = $('#input').val().split('\n');
    var output_lines = new Array();
    //Iterate over each keyword and prepend and append values
    $.each(input_words, function(i, word){
        output_lines.push($('#before').val()+' '+word+' '+$('#after').val());
    });
    //Display output in textarea
    $('#output').val(output_lines.join('\n'));
}
```

You just need to choose when you want to update the output textarea, maybe bind it so it updates every time the #input or #before and #after changes:

```
$('#input,#before,#after').on('change',update_output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I can help you to get started. My answer is not complete, but you can have a very good idea from here. Note I wrote this code to be easy to understand and I am not using sophisticated approaches on purpose.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#input").keypress(function(key){
        if(key.which == 13) {
            refreshData();
        }
    });
});

function refreshData() {
    var beforeVal = $("#before").val();
    var inputLines = $("#input").val().split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);
    var desiredOutputVal = "";
    for(var i=0; i<inputLines.length; i++) {
        desiredOutputVal += beforeVal + inputLines[i] + "\n";
    }
    $("#output").val(desiredOutputVal); 
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <textarea id="input"></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="before" />
    <input type="text" id="after" />
    <textarea id="output"></textarea>
</form>
</body></html>
```